# Silverlight 5 Out of Browser http streaming of JavaScript blocks using webbrowser

Tags: javascript, silverlight, long-polling, out-of-browser, script-tag

Some background: I have inherited a working Silverlight application which behaves as follows:

- there is an iframe on the host html page which itself connects to another page.
- this page is a long-lived request which returns a series of `<script>parent.callFunction(data)</script>` blocks
- these scripts are executed, call up to their parent, which in turn calls the silverlight app itself using the html bridge.

In this way we have a working streaming data service via the browser into the app, but I can't make this work out-of-browser.

By using a WebBrowser control and `window.external.notify` I'm able to recreate most of the functionality described, but the script blocks in the long lived request are not acknowledged or executed by the WebBrowser control.

**Is there any way I can force the WebBrowser control to execute these script blocks?**

Or, is there another way of achieving the goal? I've been chasing this problem on and off with fiddler for over a week before understanding what the problem was, and now can't find any information. [Microsoft's idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550717%28VS.95%29.aspx) seems to be to create my own version of IE using WinForms - but this seems like a poor substitute.

Comment: So in the end we just ended up creating a new WinForms app and linking to the live version using a `WebBrowser` control, but I'd really like to hear some kind of answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried your exact scenario, my guess is that you are hitting a [cross domain policy violation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) when running OOB.
If you haven't yet, try the OOB `elevated trust` application route and see if that can solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case. The OOB app thinks it is running on the same domain anyway so does not have this problem - as evidenced by other script blocks being executed (from http requests which complete, but are external to the app). Elevated trust also tested in OOB mode but was not relevant to this problem. The only script blocks which do not execute are those from http responses which have not ended.